# How to download Guava Libraries for Netbeans?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, guava

I want to use Guava TreeMultiset data structure in my java program. I use netbeans to code my program. However, I am a beginner and I don't know how I can include and import Guava libraries in netbeans. I've searched the web, but things were not clear to me.

Can anyone please tell me how I can use Guava in Netbeans?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using maven, right click on dependencies and select add dependency, then search for guava.

If it is a standard project, right click on libraries and then add library, then add the jar for guava manually

Comment: Thank you so much for your useful answer, guava is working very well now.

Comment: great!, you can accept the answer by clicking on the arrow next to it :)

Comment: Yes, I will do that :)

Comment: Where can i find the .JAR file ?

I tried to import the .ZIP file (which contains every java classes) and it appears in my libraries.

But i can't use it since the package is not visible.